# how to get one nested data in Fast Api from Concatenate values with same keys in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, nested-lists, nested-for-loop

i am using fast Api SQLAlchemy. i have a **'Writing_Test_Name'** models

```
class Writing_Test_Name(Base):
    __tablename__ = properties.Writing_Test_Name

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True) 
    book_id=Column(Integer,ForeignKey('tbl_stu_adm-pricing_plan-book.id'))
    book_name=Column(String)
    writing_test=Column(String)
    writing_test_description=Column(String)
    writing_pattern = relationship('Book', back_populates='writing_items')
```

form this model I want to get the data in nested models like this:

```
 [
  { 
    "book_id": 1
    "book_name": "Bangla 1st paper",
    "writing_items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "writing_test": "string-1",
        "writing_test_description": "string-1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "writing_test": "string-2",
        "writing_test_description": "string-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    "book_id": 2
    "book_name": "Bangla 2nd paper",
    "writing_items": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "writing_test": "string-3",
        "writing_test_description": "string-3"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "writing_test": "string-4",
        "writing_test_description": "string-4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i alreday tried many ways but i am not properly getting the items like this, I tried this

```
def get_one_group(id: int, db: Session):
    
        data =  db.execute('SELECT id, book_id, book_name, writing_test, 
                      writing_test_description FROM 
                      public."tbl_study_content-writing_test_name";')
        role_has_permission = data.mappings().all()

        x=role_has_permission

        from collections import defaultdict

        groups = defaultdict(list)
        for test in x:
            book_id = test['book_id']
            book_name=test['book_name']
            print(book_id)
            #book_name  = test.pop('book_name')
            #z=str(subject_id) + book_name
            groups[book_name].append(test) 

            result = [ { 'book_name' :k, 'writing_items' : v } for k, v 
                                                      in groups.items()]

        

       
        while groups[book_id] == id :
            
            return result
```

But I am getting null response when i tried to get the specific book id with **while groups[book_id] == id** . what was my mistake.

Comment: What is `while groups[book_id] == id :` supposed to do? It only compares a list agains a single value - which will be False, and then returns nothing. If you want to return the group, use `return groups.get(id)` instead, which will return `None` if no group matches, or the group if found. It also seems weird iterating over `groups.items()` inside your `for` loop; did you mean to just `return result` regardless? I'd also like to point out that you can usually define a `relationship` in your SQLAlchemy model and then get this automagically handled for you.

Comment: i tried group = db.query(models.Writing_Test_Name).filter(models.Writing_Test_Name.book_id == id).first() relationship but not getting desired data

Comment: That's a separate query, not really a defined `relationship`. Also, if you want more than one entry, you want to use `all()` instead of using `first()`  - since you want all the entries and not just a single one.

Comment: how can get this model data in nested model,? i am get this data like my desired nested models

Comment: You'd define `writing_items = relationship('Writing_Test_Name')` in your `Book` model, and SQLAlchemy would know how to join them automagically as long as you've defined the `book_id` field as a `ForeignKey`.